# Create a file with the sample, gene, and line count - linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to create a file called depths that has the name of the sample, the gene, and then the number of times that gene is in the sample. The below code is what I have currently, but the output just has the file names. Ex. file name=ERR034597.MTCYB.sam

I want the file to have ERR034597 MTCYB 327, for example.

```
for i in genes/${i}.sam
filename=$(basename $i)
n_rows=$(cat $i | wc -l)
echo $filename $n_rows > depths
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
for i in genes/${i}.sam
```

you're accessing the variable `i` before it has been assigned yet. This shouldn't work. What you probably want to do is

```
for i in genes/*.sam
filename=$(basename "$i")
n_rows=$(wc -l "$i")
echo "$filename" $n_rows > depths
```

And just another note. It's good practice to avoid unnecessary calls to `cat` and always quote the variables holding filenames.

Comment: or better `n_rows=$(wc -l < "$i")` to avoid appending the filename.

Comment: Will this work with a submission script? This is for a project. Our professor won't answer any questions and I've been super confused. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @LaurenKirsch What is a submission script?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are attempting, then you need a few more steps to isolate the first part of the filename, (e.g. `ERR034597`) and the gene (e.g. `MTCYB`) before writing the information to `depths`. You also need to consider whether you are replacing the contents of `depths` on each iteration (e.g. using `>`) or *Appending* to `depths` with `>>`.

Since your tag is [Linux], all we can presume is you have a POSIX shell and not an advanced shell like bash. To remove the `.sam` extension from `filename` and then separate into the first part and the gene before obtaining the line count, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

:> depths       # truncate depths (optional - if required)

for i in genes/*.sam; do                        # loop over all .sam files
    filename="$(basename "$i")"                 # remove path from name
    filename="${filename%.sam}"                 # trim .sam extension from name
    gene="${filename##*.}"                      # trim to last '.' save as gene
    filename="${filename%.$gene}"               # remove gene from end of name
    n_rows=$(wc -l < "$i")                      # get number of lines in file
    echo "$filename $gene $n_rows" >> depths    # append vales to depths
done
```

Which would result in `depths` containing lines similar to:

```
ERR034597 MTCYB 92
```

(where the test file contained 92 lines)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.